# Generate Array of Arrays with no Matching combinations

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am having some trouble with the next step here to ensure that each array combination is unique. Using vanilla javascript I am trying to generate an array of arrays with two number values. I am looking to compare the arrays and ensure that no two array combinations are the same.

```
  var grid = []
  var columns = []
  var rows = []

  for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) { columns.push(i) }
  for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { rows.push(i) }

  while (grid.length < 9) {
    const col = columns[Math.floor(Math.random() * columns.length)]
    const row = rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rows.length)]
    grid.push([col, row])

    // Compare arrays, remove like combinations and re-compare would go in here
  }

**Example output of grid**
 
0: [2, 2]
1: [6, 1]
2: [2, 2]
3: [4, 3]
4: [3, 3]
5: [7, 3]
6: [7, 3]
7: [3, 3]
8: [4, 3]
```

I would like the above combination to be unique so there are no duplicates so [1, 2] [1,3] is ok but [1, 2] [1, 2] is not. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of "removing duplicates", just create a hash and don't push the combination on if its already been done:

```
var gridHash = {};
while (grid.length < 9) {
  const col = columns[Math.floor(Math.random() * columns.length)]
  const row = rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rows.length)];
  var key = col+'|'+ row;
  if(!gridHash[key]) {
    grid.push([col, row]);
    gridHash[key]=true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store entries in an object and check if they have been added before.

```js
  var grid = []
  var columns = []
  var rows = []
  var obj = {}

  for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) { columns.push(i) }
  for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) { rows.push(i) }

  while (grid.length < 9) {
    const col = columns[Math.floor(Math.random() * columns.length)]
    const row = rows[Math.floor(Math.random() * rows.length)]
    const key = ':' + row + ':' + col;
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue
    obj[key] = true
    grid.push([col, row])
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(grid))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `reduce` to quickly check if a array contains an item.

```
contains = (pos1)=>grid.map((pos2)=>(pos2[0]==pos1[0] && pos2[1]==pos2[1])).reduce((a,b)=>a||b, false)
```

Basically, this checks for every point in the grid if both the X and Y coordinate match. Then, we use reduce as an easy way to make a dynamically sized `or`.